# JavaScript modal is unable to open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a note taker app that gives you the option to view said note in a modal whenever the button is clicked. The HTML for the note and modal is dynamically generated by event listeners. There are two ways the close the modal, by clicking the "X" button or by clicking outside of the modal. The program has full functionality whenever only one note is generated, but once I generate a second note the code breaks down. Once this happens only I'm able to open the modal of the first note generated, but not close it. And the second one won't open whatsoever. How could I fix this issue?

```js
class Input {
  constructor(note) {
    this.note = note;
  }
}

class UI {
  addNote(input) {
    // Get table body below form
    const content = document.querySelector(".content");
    // Create tr element
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    // Insert new HTML into div
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>
        ${input.note}
        <br><br>
        <button class="modalBtn">View Note</button>
      </td>
    `;

    content.appendChild(row);

    // Event listener to make modal
    document.querySelector(".modalBtn").addEventListener("click",       function(e) {
      // Get container div
      const container = document.querySelector(".container");
      // Create div
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      // Assign class to it
      div.className = "modal";
      // Insert HTML into div
      div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <div>
            <p>${input.note}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
      // Append the new div to the container div
      container.appendChild(div);
      
      // Get modal
      const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

      // Event listener to close modal when "x" is clicked
      document.querySelector(".closeBtn").addEventListener("click",       function() {
        container.removeChild(modal);
      });

      // Event listener to close when the window outside the modal       is clicked
      window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (e.target === modal) {
          container.removeChild(modal);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Clear input field
  clearInput() {
    note.value = "";
  }
  
}

// Event listener for addNote
document.getElementById("note-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  // Get form value
  const note = document.getElementById("note").value;
  // Instantiate note
  const input = new Input(note);

  // Instantiate UI
  const ui = new UI();

  // Validate form (make sure input is filled)
  if (note === "") {
    // Error alert
    alert("Please fill in text field!");
  }
  else {
    // Add note
    ui.addNote(input);

    // Clear input field
    ui.clearInput();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
h5 {
    color: green;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20% auto;
    padding: 30px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-direction: 1s;
}

.closeBtn {
    color: #aaa;
    /* float: right; */
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.closeBtn:hover,
.closeBtnBtn:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.closeBtn + div {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

@keyframes modalopen {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" integrity="sha512-5fsy+3xG8N/1PV5MIJz9ZsWpkltijBI48gBzQ/Z2eVATePGHOkMIn+xTDHIfTZFVb9GMpflF2wOWItqxAP2oLQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Note Taker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Note Taker</h1>
    <h5>Add A New Note:</h5>
    <form id="note-form">
      <div>
        <label>Note:</label>
        <textarea name="Note" id="note" class="u-full-width">               </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Add                   Note</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <table>
      <tbody class="content"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all.. I love your syntaxt!! Best I've seen so far! second.. you do a general query Selector and don't handle them separately. Can that be an issue?

EDIT:
Because of reasons I'll reformulated my answer..

`document.querySelector('class')` returns an Html-Collection with DOM element references containing the specified html class and should be handled separately.

Comment: This is more of a comment, than an answer.

Comment: I answered the question... :/